# Update Cart count with AJAX success - WordPress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

In my custom WordPress theme, I placed my Cart icon in the `header.php`, where with other things I placed it in an `<li class="user-cart">`. I placed the db Query within this `<li>` and with the "Add to Cart" button I'm trying to **reload the `<li>`** so that it can query again and show the updated count of the products added.

On AJAX success I can do it using:

```
success: function (data) {
   $('.user-cart').load(window.location.href + ' .user-cart');
}
```

When I'm clicking on the Add to Cart button, it's reloading the `<li>` with the update `count()`, but it's taking another `<li>` within the parent `<li>`, like:

```
<li class="user-cart">
   <li class="user-cart">
      <a href="/view-cart"><span class="user-cart-icon"></span>&nbsp;15</a>
   </li> <!-- cloned li -->
</li> <!-- parent or original li -->
```

But the good part is that, the cloned `<li>` loads only once, on the first click after a page reload, then all the count comes within the second `<li>`.

What's the wrong part in my code? I don't want any duplicate `<li>` — just want to reload the `<li class="user-cart">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try like this

```
success: function (data) {
   $('.user-cart').load(window.location.href + ' .user-cart a');
}
```

**P.S** *what does that response `data` contain? I would prefer to use that to update the count, without making an additional request to server*